# Codename One ORM

Tags: codenameone

Is the ORM in Codename One similar to hibernate? 
I can't find any detailed examples.
I have seen one tutorial to persist objects. But i'm more interested in populating the database with XML during install and then retrieve data on query.

Or, would it be possible to use hibernate with Codename one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codename One doesn't have an ORM. It has an Externalizable implementation similar to Java serialization and manual SQL support but no ORM and nothing like Hibernate.

The reason why that is missing is pretty simple, ORM's require either reflection or bytecode manipulation. Codename One translates code to C for iOS thus discarding reflection meta-data, on Android the code is obfuscated to comply with Googles guidelines (again breaking ORM). So a traditional ORM would be problematic to integrate.

Comment: on Android, ORMLite works well. Even if the code is obfuscated. I believe it should be possible for you to write something similar in Codename1.

Comment: The trick is not to use reflection. E.g. Steve Hannah did a POJO to JSON mapping tool that works in Codename One by using a bytecode preprocessor: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/json-to-pojo-mapping.html this is effectively seamless to our build servers. You can do the same with a source generator etc. These are use cases we are looking at but we need enough serious developer interest to promote such features to the forefront.

Comment: @shai-almog Any updates available in terms of ORM-ish behaviors in CN1?

Comment: Not quite although I have given this some thought recently especially in relation to JSON mapping but also in the sense of simpler/better persistence thru properties. I don't think this fits very well in a stackoverflow discussion though. I would suggest the discussion forum for this specific brainstorm.